# How to call two urls on click of form submit in django template using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

I have this form, user login form in django

```
<form method="post" id="loginSubmit" action="{% url 'auth_login' %}">{% csrf_token %}
<table>
<tr>
    <td>{% trans form.username.label_tag %}</td>
    <td>{{ form.username }}</td>
    <td><i class="fi-torso"></i></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>{% trans form.password.label_tag %}</td>
    <td>{{ form.password }}</td>
    <td><i class="fi-key"></i></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td colspan="3"><input type="submit" id="Login" class="button expand" value="{% trans "Login" %}" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

I have to call two urls on click of submit button, as through action it send one url and another through ajax as bellow:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {     

    $("#Login").click(function() { 

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "{% url 'user_group' group_name %}",
            datatype: "html",
            data: $("#loginSubmit").serialize(),
            success: function(data) {                   
            }
        });   

    });

});

</script>
```

What happens is, when i click submit button in login form it takes first action url i.e. `auth_login` and redirects to it and doesn't call ajax url.
As I know the reason that form submits at its action url this action happens at server side and ajax call happens at client side and server side redirection happens first then client side. but how to tackle such situation, as I want to call two urls on same submit button.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {     

    $("#Login").click(function(e) { 
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "{% url 'user_group' group_name %}",
            datatype: "html",
            data: $("#loginSubmit").serialize(),
            success: function(data) {                   
            }
        });

        $("#loginSubmit").submit();
    });

});

</script>
```

if that doesn't work then put `$("#loginSubmit").submit()` on ajax's `success` function, but this time form will be submit after ajax response, you know.

EDIT: using `complete` callback function of JQuery.ajax instead of `success`is more accurate here.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your opinion iskorum, I have already did this but it doesnt work , as you said form submit in ajax success function, i did this but it calls after successful return from ajax call , then what happens is, i have to click two times on submit button , at first click it returns from ajax and at second click it redirects to action url. but i want it to happen at same instance at one click itself.  Please suggest

Comment: There is `completed` function for ajax (https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) it will be call in all condition. after ajax request finished form will be submit, no need for second click? Does this help?

Comment: Ohh , Thats great,amazing , it works. Thank you iskorum. but one more thing i want to clear ,when i create input type="button" for submit then only it works if i do input type="submit" then before sending request to ajax call it calls the form action url, and request goes to server side. Is there any way on forms submit button call two urls.

Comment: `e.preventDefault();` must work here? This prevents de default action of element (here it is submitting the form). We call `$("#loginSubmit").submit();` because we prevented submitting.

Comment: Ohh , thanx iskorum. You are genius. I have completely solved with my issue. e.preventDefault() works. Previously i have just forgot to mention e.preventDefault() statement in my code. But now its fine. thanx for your help. Its amazing. stackoverflow rocks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this sunny

```
      $(document).ready(function() 
   {     

   $("#Login").click(function() { 

        $.ajax({
         // create an AJAX call...
            data: $("#loginSubmit").serialize(), // get the form data
            type: 'GET', // GET or POST
            url: '{% url 'user_group' group_name %}', // the file to call
            success: function (data) {
            $("#state_table").html(data);
                //alert('ajax call suceessfully');
             },
             error: function(data) {
            $("#state_table").html("Something went wrong!");
            }
        });
     });
  });
```